# How to check globally if getJSON was completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the snippet below to push elements into an array:

```
let arr = [];
$.getJSON('file.json', function (data) { push elements into arr });
```

When I access `arr` within the select event of `autocomplete` I am able to access length property and get the element at index:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: arr, 
  select: function(event, ui) { console.log(arr.lenght); } });
```

But when I access the `arr` from elsewhere, I'm unable to access it. 
My guess is `autocomplete` was fired *after* `$.getJSON` has completed? Without moving the code I want to run inside `$.getJSON`, is there a way to globally detect `$.getJSON` has completed successfully?

Comment: The problem is because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. Therefore you're probably trying to use `arr` before any values have been put in to it. To fix this, put the `autocomplete()` call *inside* the `$.getJSON` clalback handler. That being said, you can avoid the problem entirely by making `autocomplete` make the AJAX request, instead of doing it manually. Assuming this is the jQueryUI autocomplete, read the [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use "done" method, it's in the official documentation https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ for example:

```
let arr = [];

$.getJSON(
    'file.json', 
    function (data) { push elements into arr }
).done(function(){

   console.log("Success");

});
```